# DB2 Query Taking too much time to complete DATA_PHYSICAL_READS is higher

Tags: sql, db2, query-performance

My query is much long time approx 8 mins to complete.

I checked and found that max time is being taken due to data_physical_read is too much.

Can someone suggest how to lower this

```
select BP_NAME,DATA_PHYSICAL_READS, DATA_HIT_RATIO_PERCENT, INDEX_PHYSICAL_READS,INDEX_HIT_RATIO_PERCENT 
from SYSIBMADM.MON_BP_UTILIZATION
```

```
BP_NAME DATA_PHYSICAL_READS DATA_HIT_RATIO_PERCENT INDEX_PHYSICAL_READS INDEX_HIT_RATIO_PERCENT
IBMDEFAULTBP 6186475 99.96 3700 99.2
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), the query you are using and the execution plan. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: And state whether this was run on a cold or warm system and how big the table is.